# Rav Shimshon Raphael Hirsch: "שמח" and "צומח"

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, samson-raphael-hirsch

In [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/131127/ivdu-es-hashem-besimcha-in-practice/131128#131128) question I brought a quote that I saw in Rabbi Twersky's *[The Enemy Within](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578197635)* (Shaar Press: 2002) in his chapter entitled "Finding Joy in Life" (p.104):

> Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch points out that the Hebrew word same'ach (= happy), is closely related to the word tzome'ach (= growing). This is because human happiness is contingent on spiritual growth. If we fail to feel the joy of mitzvos, it is because we are unaware that mitzvos make us grow.

Does anyone know the source for this Rav Shimshon Raphael Hirsch?

Comment: How about עצב-עשב?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at his comments on [Genesis, 2:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.5?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

> וְכֹ֣ל ׀ שִׂ֣יחַ הַשָּׂדֶ֗ה טֶ֚רֶם יִֽהְיֶ֣ה בָאָ֔רֶץ וְכׇל־עֵ֥שֶׂב הַשָּׂדֶ֖ה טֶ֣רֶם יִצְמָ֑ח כִּי֩ לֹ֨א הִמְטִ֜יר יְהֹוָ֤ה אֱלֹהִים֙ עַל־הָאָ֔רֶץ וְאָדָ֣ם אַ֔יִן לַֽעֲבֹ֖ד אֶת־הָֽאֲדָמָֽה׃

He writes there:

> שיח מציין צמיחה באופן כללי, **ומשום כך הוא מורה גם על הצמיחה הרוחנית של האדם**. (השווה מושגים נוספים מעבודת האדמה, שיש להם גם מובן בתחום האדם, כגון: ״חרשׁ״, ״שׂעיף״ [ראה איוב ד, יג], ״מלה״ [משורש ״מלל״, ראה פירוש להלן כא, ז] ו״עצה״ = ״עץ״. ובדומה לכך: **״צמח״ = ״שמח״**, ״שוש״ = ״צוץ״.) לדעת חז״ל, ״שיח״ מציין במיוחד תפילה (בראשית רבה יג, ב): המתפלל ״שותה״ כביכול ממקור החיים הרוחניים; הוא ״משקה״ ומחייה את כל נימי פנימיותו כדי להוציא ״ציצים״ ו״פרחים״

Comment: Excellent! - It is def referenced there. I added the text into your answer.